# Displaying PDF files in Angular with ng2-pdf-viewer

Tags: angular, pdf

I'm trying to use the [ng2-pdf-viewer](https://github.com/VadimDez/ng2-pdf-viewer) component to display several PDFs from my ASP.NET Web API backend. I've added PdfViewerComponent to my module's declarations and the provided example works fine:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'example-app',
  template: `
  <div>
      <label>PDF src</label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="PDF src" [(ngModel)]="pdfSrc">
  </div>
  <pdf-viewer [src]="pdfSrc" [render-text]="true" style="display: block;">
  </pdf-viewer>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  pdfSrc: string = '/pdf-test.pdf';
}
```

The problem arise when I try to load the pdf src from my any other resource.

I first encountered CORS issues, but I later resolved this with the DomSanitizer. The new error I get whenever I try to load PDFs are:

```
ERROR Error: Invalid parameter object: need either .data, .range or .url
    at Object.getDocument (pdf.js:2867)
    at PdfViewerComponent.webpackJsonp.../../../../ng2-pdf-viewer/dist/pdf-viewer.component.js.PdfViewerComponent.loadPDF
```

I've searched high and low for a solution to the problem, but I just can't figure it out. Any help will be deeply appreciated.

If you want me to provide any additional information, please let me know.

Comment: Bro can u tell me how you  solved it as i am badly stucked

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I noticed that you've posted this question across several forums. I hope that by this time you already have this sorted out. In case you haven't, here's my solution:

So the problem is that my API (and yours I'm presuming) is returning a stream. This apparently does not work with `ng2-pdf-viewer`. What does work with it are [strings, objects, and UInt8Arrays.](https://github.com/VadimDez/ng2-pdf-viewer#src)

If, like myself, you aren't keen on changing the actual response of the API since a lot of other logic depend on it, you can instead transform it on the front end. This is done by setting the `HttpResponseType`:

```
this.http.get(
  `/url/to/photo/stream`,
  {responseType: 'arraybuffer' as 'json'}
)
```

What this essentially does is it typecasts the response which is an `arraybuffer` to something that can be consumed: `json`. This is the way I understand it though. More information about this can be found in the [Angular repository issues](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18586).

The response from this call is now readable by `ng2-pdf-viewer`!

I hope this helps!

Comment: Works perfectly fine for me now. I don't know what I did, but it suddenly worked. You answer can probably help somebody else, whose experiencing a similar issue, so will check it. Thank you very much for your response.

Comment: Same issue can u plz help

Comment: Now i am getting this error -> Warning: Indexing all PDF objects

Comment: Thanks a lot this solution helped a lot.