# ng2-pdf-viewer Error: Invalid parameter object: need either .data, .range or .url

Tags: angular, pdf, url

I am trying to use ng2-pdf-viewer in my Angular 7 project. Initially, I was having a cors issue which I solved [with this advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43068590/ng2-pdf-viewer-access-control-allow-origin?rq=1). Now, I am experiencing the following error:

```
Invalid parameter object: need either .data, .range or .url
at Object.getDocument (pdf.js:7919)
at PdfViewerComponent.push.../../../node_modules/ng2-pdf-viewer/ng2-pdf-viewer.es5.js.PdfViewerComponent.loadPDF
```

I tried to implement the answer [from this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46753522/displaying-pdf-files-in-angular-with-ng2-pdf-viewer), but had no luck. It may be correct and I am misunderstanding how to implement.

my ts:

```js
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core'
import {DomSanitizer, SafeUrl} from '@angular/platform-browser'

@Component({
    selector:'app-help-dialog',
    templateUrl:'./helpDialog.html',
    styleUrls:['../../style/style.css']
})
export class HelpDialog implements OnInit {

    pdfSource:string = 'https://url/to/my/pdf.pdf'
    safeUrl:SafeUrl

    constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.safeUrl = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(this.pdfSource)
    }
}
```

and my template:

```
<pdf-viewer [src]='safeUrl'>
</pdf-viewer>
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using url, then what you should do is just use `pdfSource` instead of `safeUrl`.

If you are using base64 encoding this is how I fixed it:
In .html file

```
<pdf-viewer [src]="pdfSource"></pdf-viewer>
```

In .ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
        ...
})
export class testComponent implements OnInit {
    base_64_string = 'this_is_where_you_put_base_64';
    pdfSource;

    constructor() {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.pdfSource = this._base64ToArrayBuffer(this.pdfSource);
    }

    _base64ToArrayBuffer(base64) {
        const binary_string = window.atob(base64);
        const len = binary_string.length;
        const bytes = new Uint8Array(len);
        for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            bytes[i] = binary_string.charCodeAt(i);
        }
        return bytes.buffer;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:

`<pdf-viewer [src]="safeUrl.changingThisBreaksApplicationSecurity"></pdf-viewer>`

you can just access the url via .changingThisBreaksApplicationSecurity,
hope this help you or someone else with same issue.

reply this post if there is another requirement.